# В WordPress поле в таблице wp_terms

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Разбираюсь как работает плагин `Polylang` и в таблице `wp_terms` с `id`, которое связывает несколько постов с одинкаовым контентом, но различными языками в столбцах name и slug засечены значения `pll_5d236f43322d0`, `pll_5d34e761473eb`. Как генерируются эти значения и вообще играют ли они какую-то роль. Занимаюсь миграцией постов на Wp и нужно эти поля генерировать.
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Не нужно ничего генерировать. Не нужно вообще лезть в базу. Нужно использовать АПИ ВП. А конкретно для импорта контента - плагины.

Comment: @SeVlad в любом случае человек до меня посты в базу внёс руками. Переводов и категорий нет

Comment: То, что другой натворил нужно удалить и сделать заново, но правильно.

Comment: А зачем вы смотрите в базе? Гляньте в код плагина. Хотя я не понимаю, что вы хотите сделать.